# How can I pass data to the next view controller when it is loaded programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Suppose I have three view controllers in a Main.storyboard. Two of the three, `vc_login` and `vc_studyDesc` load the other view controller using a UIButton with 'present modally' option.

The other one `vc_signup` has a UIButton, which may go back to the previous controller. To implement this, I used the following methods:

`vc_studyDesc` has an identifier of `studyDesc`; I let it pass its identifier to `vc_signup`. In the same way, `vc_login` has `login` as an identifier.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if sender as! UIButton == qnaSignUp {
        let signup = segue.destinationViewController as! vc_signup
        signup.latestVC = "studyDesc"}}
```

This one is in the `UIViewController` class for `vc_signup`. By referencing a string `latestVC`, the method determines which VC to move on.

```
@IBAction func backBtnClick(sender: UIButton) {
    print("latestVS: \(latestVC)")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(latestVC)
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
    print("check check")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)}
```

The problem I have is that the app gets terminated when `vc_studyDesc` is called by `vc_signup`. I found that this is because I missed a significant variable which must be loaded in `vc_signup`.

`vc_studyDesc` has some data to be referenced from Firebase when it is loaded. I did this by loading a variable `postID` from the prior vc to `vc_studyDesc`; which is `vc_list`.

So I just saved `postID` using `NSUserdefaults.standardUserDefaults()`. It is solved but I'm wondering if there's any way to pass data using the way I used in `vc_signup`.

As far as I see, I cannot find any way to pass the data into `vc_studyDesc.swift`; for the vc is chosen by its identifier..

Can I pass the variable I want in the way I want?? And adding tags would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple problems with this design.

When you instantiate a viewController you are creating a new instance of that class, and presenting it adds it to the stack. Think of the stack like a deck of cards, you start with one card and then add or remove them, the top card being the visible vc. When you are going back to studyDesc you are instantiating and presenting it so you will have 3 VCs in your stack, of which two are studyDesc (the one you started with and the one you add when you try to go back)

To remove a VC from the stack you can use

```
dismissViewController(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or if you have the VCs in a navigation controller you can use

```
popViewControllerController(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

in terms of passing information between viewControllers, if the info is in the VC you use to present your new controller you can use prepareForSegue like you already have. To pass information back you should use a delegate pattern. So to implement a delegate pattern in this case you would do the following:

Declare a protocol (not inside your classes, above there but below your import's)

```
protocol SignUpDelegate {
    signInCompleted(infoToPass: AnyObject)
}
```

Then have your studyDesc class conform to this protocol and implement the function signInCompleted

```
StudyDescVC: UIViewController, SignUpDelegate {

    func signInCompleted(infoToPass: AnyObject) {
        // do what you want with the info here
    }

}
```

Then in your signUpVc add a var delegate (which will be used to call the signInCompeleted function)

```
class SignInVC: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SignUpDelegate!

    func finishedSigningIn() {
        delegate.signInCompleted(infoToPass: //yourinfo)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

And then in your prepareForSegue set the delegate

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if sender as! UIButton == qnaSignUp {
    let signup = segue.destinationViewController as! vc_signup
    signup.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(latestVC) as! YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_NAME
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
    vc.name = "Andrew"
    print("check check")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


    //set a variale or property to your viewController

   class YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_NAME: UIViewController {
    var name: String?

}
```